# Error in installation from terminal

Tags: software-installation, 15.04

i am using ubuntu15.04.
when i am trying to install to something in my pc from terminal then following problem arise:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I dont understand what its mean. 
someone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that another process/application uses the package system. Probably you have the Ubuntu Software Center running or you are currently installing software updates. So close the Software Center before you use apt-get on the command line.